# Why does the 'TuckTheTorld' function not work when called from another file?

Tags: php

connect_db.php:

```
<?php
$servername = "1.1.1.1";
$username = "root";
$password = "nope, not making this public :P";
$dbname = "seminarfach";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
//$conn = new mysqli(null, $username, $password, $dbname, null, '/cloudsql/seminarfach-abi-links:data');

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

echo "<p>Connected successfully</p>";

// Set charset to UTF-8
if (!$conn->set_charset("utf8")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $conn->error);
    exit();
}

function TuckTheTorld() {
    $conn->close();
}
?>
```

This is the file that connects to my database, and it is called with `require "connect_db.php";` in the file that needs a connection. Now I wanted to create a function that is called to close the connection to the DB. That is the TuckTheTorld function. I named it that to make sure I don't use any keywords or overwirte any other functions.

The problem is that when I call `TuckTheTorld()` I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function close() on a non-object in path_to_file\connect_db.php on line 26
```

Why do I get that error?

Comment: Yea... first thing that came to my mind somehow... I have no idea why, but I was sure that it will not conflict with anything else...

Comment: Now that is to long, now that it works I've named it closeConn() to make sense. The name was purly for testing. But I'll name it something more appopriate I ask a question next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import the `$conn` object into the functions namespace by using the `global` keyword (there is nothing called `$conn` in the functions namespace because `$conn` resides in the global files namespace).

Just replace your function with:

```
function TuckTheTorld() {
    global $conn;
    $conn->close();
}
```

This should now work for you.

Comment: now they'll need to rename their function call ;-) `fuchTheWorld` => `fuc*TheWorld`

Comment: Sometimes I don't spell things right... Just corrected it. Thanks fo the hint.

Comment: I thought you were being *polite* ;-) and civilized hehe

Comment: Sometimes it's not a such good idea to flag a mod...

Comment: Well whoever did flag it, was a good move. They could've used a substitute word for it. It may be a hoax also. They've been a member for a year now and they post that? Kind of fishy if you ask me.

Comment: Thank you! I'm still learning php.

Comment: Somehow everybody is still learning php. Life long learning.